# Put half my hard drive offline, and the other half online

Tags: partitioning, virtual-machine, external-hard-drive

Is it possible to put half my external hard drive offline, while keeping the other half online?

I've shrunk my drive, so I've got 2 halves, and I know how to put the entire disk offline, but I need half of it on my computer, and the other half on my Hyper-V Virtual Machine...which requires the disk being offline

Help appreciated!!

Comment: No; What you want is not possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound) in the comments, this is impossible